# Emacs. Изменение названия (title) фрейма

Tags: emacs

Настроил emacs таким образом, что в заголовке фрейма (окна) он отображает имя текущего буфера. Задача такова. Нужно чтоб emacs отображал в заголовке какой-нибудь символ (напр., *), если буфер модифицирован. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Есть два полезных крючка: `first-change-hook` и `after-save-hook`. Можна к ним подключить функции, модифицирующие имя буфера:

```
(defvar *modified-marker* "*")

(defun mark-modified ()
  "Добавить знак перед именем буфера"
  (let ((buffer-name (buffer-name)))
    (rename-buffer (concat *modified-marker* buffer-name))))

(defun unmark-modified ()
  "Удалить знак с имени буфера"
  (let ((buffer-name (buffer-name)))
    (rename-buffer (string-trim-left buffer-name *modified-marker*))))

;; Подключить функции к крючком
(add-hook 'first-change-hook 'mark-modified)
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'unmark-modified)
```

Есть ещё проблема функции `undo`. Это можна наверно выполнить используя `advice-add`. Посмотри [здесь](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).